# Can I skip the whole wp_head function?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to benchmark my blog, and I see that all these plugins are putting a whole lot of crap in my code! Since I'm doing most of what I need by myself, I don't think my very few plugins need extra help. I tried fiddling a bit, and now I've gotten to a point where I just remarked the `wp_head()` call.

Everything seems to be working fine, but I'm afraid I might have broken something I'm not aware of. Does anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

The main purpose of `wp_head` is to provide a hook for plugins/themes to

1. Alter or add new meta tags
2. Add required CSS and stylesheets
3. Add required javascript files

So not calling this function will break themes and plugins that use it for one of those purposes, at the very least. If you have no such plugins, you won't break WordPress itself by not calling it. It is *not* required by WordPress itself.

Comment: turns out i needed that for just one plugin, but i put some unregisterers in my functions file, so its a bit better, but im still calling unnecesarry prototype.js and some more libraries i dont use..    
is there anything else i can do?
thanx for the tips.